# WhiteRaccoon iOS 4.2 errors

Tags: ios, ftp

I have a app with the WhiteRaccoon framework installed.
I cant compile it as it gives me errors with anything to do with retain or release in WhiteRaccoon.m/h.
Any ideas whats going on?
Thanks.
By the way, I have added the CFNetwork framework. Any ideas?

Comment: The latest version of the library supports ARC out of the box.

Comment: Ah great. Thanks Valentin! Can I use it without ARC?

Comment: Only the prev versions can be used without ARC.

Comment: Do prev versions work with the current IOS?

Comment: Sure, but you have to use the solution below to exclude it as non-arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is probably using ARC and WhiteRaccoon probably isn't.

You can either convert whiteRaccoon (whatever that is) to ARC or exclude the whiteRaccoon files by adding the following compiler flags to it's source files `-fno-objc-arc`.

To do that click the project on the left hand side then go to the "Build Phases"-> "Compile Sources" look for the white Raccoon .m files and add the -fno-objc-arc under the compiler flags section.

Another option would be to compile the WhiteRaccoon framework into a static library and as this to your project.

Comment: based on a quick look at the code inside whiteRaccoon. I recommend that you exclude those files from using ARC as it'll probably give you strange results.  To do that click the project on the left hand side  then go to the "Build Phases"-> "Compile Sources" look for the white Raccoon .m files and add the  -fno-objc-arc under the compiler flags section.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer! I shall try it out some time this week and il be sure to report back. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much! That did the trick for the .m file. But there is one line in .h which is giving me an error.  NSOutputStream    *writeStream;     Is whats giving me the error. The error is:WhiteRaccoon.h:69:24: ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions I have tried adding the flags that I added to .m but still no luck. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: add the following __unsafe_unretained to the start of the instance declaration. For example if you have an struct with writeStream in side of it, ass __unsafe_unretained NSOutputStream *writeStream;

Comment: @JamerTheProgrammer hi friend i am also using this but i dont now how to use it in code i am setting my username and password and path and hostname in url but connect not happening pls help me in this i am try last two days